# Best place to store view level javascript in an MVC app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For each view I'm creating in my MVC app I will typically have a separate Javascript include that will perform various interactions with the DOM.

With WebForms I used to store the .js file next to the ASPX page, e.g.:

```
mywebform.aspx
mywebform.aspx.js
```

What is the best way to store view level javascript includes in MVC? Currently I'm creating them using the following naming convention.

```
scripts/{controller}/{action}.js
```

I am then passing a dynamically created path from the action controller to the view and binding in Razor to the shared layout.

```
@Section viewscript
    <script src='@ViewData("ViewScript")'/>
End Section
```

Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this? I feel with this method I will be spending a lot of time trawling through folders to locate the script. If I can reduce the number of clicks to get from a view to the associated script that would make things more efficient.

Comment: I follow the same pattern you do for locating the .js files: a folder for the controller and then a .js file for the script.  I'm not sure if you are a user of ReSharper or not, but I am - and that is what I use to eliminate the clicks and having to dig for the file.  I just use the "Go to File" keyboard command and type in the what I need.  Very quick and easy. 
(note: I do not work for JetBrains nor am I compensated by them.  I just love the product.)

Comment: I have ReSharper but it's switched off on this project as there are a mountain of inspector warnings. Once I clean up I will reactivate it, if ReSharper can get me to the script in a couple of clicks that would be great :)

Comment: Excellent.  You can use the "Ctrl + Shift + T" for Go to File or "Ctrl + T" for Go to Everything.

Here is the ReSharper 9 default keymap for Visual Studio:
https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper90DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf

Comment: If the script is specific only to the view, why not render it inline?

Comment: @ste-fu that is an option but I prefer to have the clean separation if I can. I don't want to wade through several hundred lines of JS to get to the markup. Plus I can keep it minified in a separate include.